# Access local web services remotely without a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, remote-access, self-hosting

I have a collection of raspberry pis running a number of web-services on my home network, things such as a [VScode webserver](https://github.com/cdr/code-server) or a [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instance.

It is often helpful for me to be able to securely access these services when I am out and about. Usually I connect to my home network with a VPN - which works fine.

However often I am working on computers that I cant install a VPN on.

Without setting up lots of port-forwarding rules (insecure+++) is there a way I can securely access the webservices on my home network using only a browser?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Set up a *reverse proxy* that acts as a frontend for all your services – it will handle authentication before it forwards any requests, and the proxy software itself is safe to expose to the internet.

Also it'll let you put all services on the same standard port; it'll let you use subdomains; and it'll handle HTTPS for those services which can't (or indeed for *all* services).

For example, if you use Apache httpd as the reverse proxy, the usual `AuthType Basic` settings work exactly the same for proxied locations as they do for locally-hosted pages. (Same goes for `auth_basic` in Nginx, and I'm sure HAproxy supports authentication as well.)